# pgfplots line does not show up

Tags: pgfplots, plot, graphs

I am trying to draw a line of best fit through my data, this is what I am trying to do.

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\title{Document}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymax=1.5,
            ymin=0,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=0.4,
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$Mass (g)$,
            ylabel=$Period (s)$,
            title={Our Data},
            xticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/precision=3,
                /pgf/number format/fixed
            },
        ]
            \addplot [only marks] table {
                0.1 0.428
                0.141421356237 0.529
                0.22360679775 0.729
                0.316227766017 1.131
                0.264575131106 0.931
                0.173205080757 0.648
            };
            \addplot[color=blue, samples=5, domain=0:0.4]{3.56011*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

But I only get the data points and not the line of best fit:

[image: latex graph]

I have tried removing the domain and tweaking the samples but to no avail. How do I get the line to show up?

Comment: I started working on another part of the document, and then it worked. If anybody knows what happened please let me know lol

Comment: Your document example si not complete and therefore not compilable. Please add preamble with packages needed to compile it. I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: If I add `\usepackage{pgfplots}` to your MWE it works for me, I see the blue line. // Off-topic: Consider using the `siunitx` package to typeset units. Your labels should then be like `ylabel={Period (\unit{\second})}`.

Comment: @Zarko Fixed, now it should be compilable.

Comment: With MWE from edited answer I can't reproduce your problem Diagram has marks as well drawn blue line.

Comment: No problem also for me. I see the data points AND the blue line.

Comment: Yeah this started working for me as soon as I modified another part of the document. I have mentioned this in the first comment.